# CM pings cut off text after newlines

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

I just sent in a CM ping that looked like this*:

> Yarp garble speek garqeq, maarph kaarto blorp... (lots of lines of boring moderator speak)
>
> ingle matph KYRGH URGH SMASH

When looking at the message in /admin/users, and on the user's history page, it's cut off after the newline:

> Yarp garble speek garqeq, maarph kaarto blorp... (lots of lines of boring moderator speak)

I'm pretty sure I'm not completely insane, and that I included the ingle...SMASH prose in the textbox before clicking submit.

Can this be fixed to either (a) handle and show newlines properly, or at least (b) just condense them into spaces?

---

<sup>*translated to moderatorese to preserve the privacy of those involved. Ping me in TL or Blue Room or wherever for more details.</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure how newlines are *actually* handled, but there is a character limit that it will display there. The text of that history item actually cuts off inside the first paragraph, just before a dash, and not at the new line. So the second paragraph wouldn't be displayed here either way.

Comment: @animuson Okay, that makes a little more sense. Might be nice to put a little ellipsis or something in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completed... in that "after a fashion" kind of sense.

There's a hard limit of 400 characters on user history comments. We *could* extend it, but considering the cost of that DB migration, we'd need a more compelling reason than just creating a full copy of the (relatively) rare CM contact emails. If we need to retain that info on-site, we're likely better off just building a feature to do that than strong-arming user history into it.

Having said that, much as the cut-off is creating entertaining sentences, adding an ellipsis to indicate that the message is incomplete is trivial. The change will be live with the next build (but not apply retroactively).

Comment: "much as the cut-off is creating entertaining sentences" - ouch.

Comment: @randal'thor I kid, I kid.